# Proving the existence/non-existence of $\lim_{x\rightarrow0} x\tan\frac1x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

> Find $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0} x\tan\frac1x$$

Now I tried to find the form of the limit ($0/0$ or $0\cdot \infty$ or $\infty/\infty$), but as $x\rightarrow 0$, $\tan(1/x)$ tends to $\tan \infty$, and since $\tan x$ is unbounded unlike $\sin x$ or $\cos x$, no particular value or range can be assumed for $\tan(1/x)$.

Then I tried to find LHL and RHL.

Let $\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+} x\tan{(1/x)}=L$.

Then $\lim_{x\rightarrow0^-} x\tan{(1/x)}=-L$, since $x$ is approaching from the negative side, the input $1/x$ of $\tan$ is the negative of the input in RHL, and $\tan (-x)=-\tan x$

Now if the limit exists, then $LHL=RHL$, thus $L=0$.

Thus I got that if the limit exists, then it must be equal to $0$. But this doesn't confirm that the limit exists (and it doesn't).

Please help me in proving that the limit doesn't exist, and also please point out the mistakes (if any) in the argument I presented above (sorry for I might be weak in limits and the basics of it)

**EDIT:** As pointed out by Shubham in the comments, I forgot to take the sign of $x$ too in the $LHL$, thus rendering the argument which proved $L=0$ moot.

***THANK YOU***

Comment: What happens when $x=\frac1{(2n+1)\pi/2}$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: The main difficulty is that $tan(1/x)$ will oscillate over the entire real number domain as $x\to 0$  At all odd multiples of $\pi/2$ it jumps from $\infty$ to $-\infty$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg, That is a helpful observation for understanding why the limit won't exist (since $1/x$ would attain the value of odd multiples of $\pi/2$ more and more densely as $x\rightarrow 0$, thus it would keep jumping from $\infty$ to $-\infty$ around those points). But would this be enough to state if the question is asked in an exam? or should there be a more rigorous sort of proof?

Comment: The error in your argument about finding $LHL$ is that you took into account the negative sign inside $\tan(-1/x)$ but failed to take into account the negative sign in $-x$. All in all$$\lim_{h\to0^+}(-h)\tan(-1/h)=\lim_{h\to0^+}h\tan(1/h)$$which is the same as you will get from the right hand side approach. This was to be expected as $x\tan(1/x)$ is an even function.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I'm sorry, I forgot to take that into the account. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Rigorous statement: For any real a, there is a sequence of $x's \to 0$ where $xtan(1/x)=a$ Therefore not convergent.

Comment: @shubhamjohri  I didn't write a sequence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x\tan(1/x)$ when $x\neq 0.$

If $a_n=\frac{1}{2\pi n}$ then $f(a_n)=0$ for all $n.$ Thus $$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(a_n)=0.$$

On the other hand, let $$b_n=\frac1{2\pi n+\arctan(n)}$$

Then $$\frac{n}{(2n+1)\pi}<f(b_n)<\frac{n}{2n\pi}$$ so by the squeeze theorem, $$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(b_n)=\frac{1}{2\pi}$$

Finally, let $$c_n=\frac1{2\pi n+\arctan(n^2)}$$ and show $f(c_n)\to +\infty.$

But $a_n,b_n,c_n$ all converge to $0,$ so $$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$$ cannot exist.

(We only needed any two of these three sequences to disprove convergence.)

Answer (score -1):

The limit does not exist.
Consider the sequence $xn=\{2/n\pi\} = \{2/\pi, 1/\pi, 2/3\pi, 1/2\pi,  \}$
$y_n = x_n *\tan(x_n)$ As $x_n\to0, \tan(x_n)$ does NOT exist as $\tan(x_n)$ varies from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.

$x_n$ is well behaved, $\tan(x_n)$ is NOT. $y_n$ is not well behaved.

Comment: It is $\tan(1/x_n)$, not $\tan(x_n)$. It is not behaving nicely as the sequence of your choice doesn't lie in the domain entirely. To be precise, $x_n$ when $n$ is odd doesn't belong to the domain.